# Generate 6 numbers without repetition from the set 1 ... 49

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to generate 6 numbers without repetition from 1 to 49.
I have something like that:

```
create table zadanie1(
NAZWISKO varchar2(30),
PUNKTY number,
ID number,
constraint stud1_nazw primary key(NAZWISKO)
);



create or replace procedure "LOTTO" IS
pkt number;
begin
   loop
       BEGIN
       pkt := round(dbms_random.value(1,14),0);
       INSERT INTO ZADANIE1(PUNKTY) VALUES (pkt);
       exit;
       Exception When DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX Then 0;
       END;
end loop;
END;
```

but this doesn't seem to work. Can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 5):

```
SQL> select num 
  2  from (select rownum num 
  3        from dual 
  4        connect by level <= 49 
  5        order by dbms_random.value) 
  6  where rownum <= 6;

       NUM
----------
        10
         6
         9
        12
        22
        14
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put the 49 numbers in a table and use

```
SELECT SOME_NUMBER FROM
(
  SELECT SOME_NUMBER
  FROM TABLE_OF_NUMBERS
  ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE()
)

WHERE ROWNUM < 7
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, thx for answer. I need to add column for this table. and for every row(user) add 6 number like in lottery.

`create table zadanie1(
user varchar2(30),
PUNKTY number,
ID number,
constraint stud1_nazw primary key(NAZWISKO)
);`